# Seeder is skipping id field when creating records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

The seeder for one of my tables is failing with

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1364 **Field 'id' doesn't have a default value** (SQL: insert into
>   `tests` (`name`, `description`, `panel_id`, `units`, `minValue`,
>   `lowNote`, `maxValue`, `highNote`, `note_id`) values (A/G Ratio,
>   Albumin to Globulin Ratio, 2, , 1.2, , 2.5, , 1))

Notice the `id` field is being skipped?

Here is the migration's `up()` method:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('panel_id');
        $table->string('units');
        $table->string('minValue');
        $table->string('lowNote',512);
        $table->string('maxValue');
        $table->string('highNote',512);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('note_id');
    });
}
```

Here is part of the `TestSeeder::run()` method:

```
$tests = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'A/G Ratio',
        'description' => 'Albumin to Globulin Ratio',
        'panel_id' => 2,
        'units' => '',
        'minValue' => '1.2',
        'lowNote' => '',
        'maxValue' => '2.5',
        'highNote' => '',
        'note_id' => 1
    ],
];
```

Here is the `Test` model:

```
class Test extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'description',
    'panel_id',
    'units',
    'minValue',
    'lowNote',
    'maxValue',
    'high_note',
    'note_id'
    ];
}
```

Notice the `id` field is listed in the `$fillable` array, so why is it being skipped?

Comment: Except part of code, we need full block of code of how do you make insert data into DB. Edit your question and put whole block of TestSeeder::run() method that is responsible for data inserting. Also, advisable would be to use `$table->bigIncrements('id');` if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
```

to:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```